# focus on first feld using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator to validate form fields. For below fields:

[image]

1. Focus is at third field i.e email 2 but I want focus on first field i.e fax.
2. Error message is displayed between text both and other static text due to which alignment shifts here and there. Best possible way to display messages.
3. In few scenarios only error message is displayed but not focus due to which user is not aware of error.

Code:

```
var validator = $("#enrollmentForm").validate({
    errorElement: 'label',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        element.focus();
    },
});
```

Can someone provide a solution?

Comment: Can you show some of your validation code?

Comment: I have added code which I am using.

Comment: 2. Error message is displayed between text both and other static text due to which alignment shifts here and there. Best possible way to display messages.  This is working after changing   error.insertAfter(element); to  error.appendTo( element.next()); :

Comment: **You are causing the problem yourself with `element.focus()`.  Simply remove that one line.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own code is causing the problem you're describing.

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element);
     element.focus();  // <- this line is causing your whole problem
 },
```

By using `element.focus` within `errorPlacement`, you're telling it to focus on the element being evaluated right when it's been evaluated.  If mutiple elements are invalid at once, then focus is naturally left on the very last one that was evaluated, since the form is evaluated from top to bottom.

Demo of the problem caused by your own code: http://jsfiddle.net/6y3k6jtc/

---

Removing the `element.focus()` line totally fixes your code, because you're allowing the plugin's default focus to operate as intended.  *(By default, the plugin automatically knows to place focus on the very first invalid input element.)*

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element);
 },
```

**DEMO of working code:  http://jsfiddle.net/6y3k6jtc/1/**

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {                    
        validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Its working.  When error is displayed alignment is shifting left meaning text is moving left , what do I do for shifting right instead of left.

Comment: @bharghavivajrala hi if it works you can do +1 And accept answer.As far as your current question is concerned , i solved it.You can edit the question , i will tell you answer .Thanks!

Comment: **The OP's own code is causing his whole problem**.  He does not need `.focus()` at all as the plugin automatically handles that perfectly well.  Therefore, you do not need the `invalidHandler` with yet another call to `.focus()`.  http://jsfiddle.net/6y3k6jtc/1/

Comment: This only works on first field once, then does not set focus if form has second and so on fields in a long form.